# Открыть файл внутри которого русские буквы. С++

Tags: c++

Есть подобная таблица

`й  1081    0x439
ц   1094    0x446
у   1091    0x443
к   1082    0x43a
е   1077    0x435
н   1085    0x43d
г   1075    0x433`

Открываю ее и считываю

```css
std::fstream file("table.csv",std::fstream::in);
std::string str;
while(getline(file,str))
{
  std::cout << str << '\n' << "Русский\n";
}

Выводит в консоль:
Р№      1081    0x439
Русский
С†      1094    0x446
Русский
Сѓ      1091    0x443
Русский
Рє      1082    0x43a
Русский
Рµ      1077    0x435
```

А если вставить английские буквы, то  в консоль они будут нормально выводиться